# Conditionally loop through chromosome and position in one dataframe to chromosome and intervals in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'Chr':['1', '1', '2', '2', '3','3','4'],
         'position':[50, 500, 1030, 2005 , 3575,50, 250]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Chr':['1', '1', '1', '1',           
  '1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3'],
             'start':  
[0,100,1000,2000,3000,0,100,1000,2000,3000,0,100,1000,2000,3000],
             'end': 
 [100,1000,2000,3000,4000,100,1000,2000,3000,4000,100,1000,2000,3000,4000],
             'logr':[3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18],
             'seg':[0.2,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.3]})
```

I wanted to  conditionally loop through 'Chr' and 'position'   in df1  to 'Chr' and intervals ( where the position in df1 falls between 'start' and 'end') in df2, then add 'logr' and 'seg'column in df1

my desired output is :

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({'Chr':['1', '1', '2', '2', '3','3','4'],
         'position':[50, 500, 1030, 2005 , 3575,50, 250],
           'logr':[3, 4, 10,11, 18,13, "NA"],
             'seg':[0.2,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,"NA"]})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any attempt so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join for all combinations, then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns and last left join for add missing rows:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Chr', how='outer')
#between is by default inclusive (>=, <=) orwith parameter inclusive=False (>, <)
df3 = df3[df3['position'].between(df3.pop('start'), df3.pop('end'))]
#if need one inclusive and  another interval not (e.g. >, <=)
#df3 = df3[(df3['position'] > df3.pop('start')) & (df3['position'] <= df3.pop('end'))]
df3 = df1.merge(df3, how='left')
print (df3)
  Chr  position  logr  seg
0   1        50   3.0  0.2
1   1       500   4.0  0.5
2   2      1030  10.0  0.2
3   2      2005  11.0  0.1
4   3      3575  18.0  0.3
5   3        50  13.0  0.1
6   4       250   NaN  NaN
```

Another solution:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Chr', how='outer')
s = df3.pop('start')
e = df3.pop('end')
df3 = df3[df3['position'].between(s, e) | s.isna() | e.isna()]
#if different closed intervals
#df3 = df3[(df3['position'] > s) & (df3['position'] <= e) | s.isna() | e.isna()]
print (df3)
   Chr  position  logr  seg
0    1        50   3.0  0.2
6    1       500   4.0  0.5
12   2      1030  10.0  0.2
18   2      2005  11.0  0.1
24   3      3575  18.0  0.3
25   3        50  13.0  0.1
30   4       250   NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and
[np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import pandas pd
import numpy as np
res_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Chr'],how='outer')

res_df['check_between'] = np.where((res_df['position']>=res_df['start'])&(res_df['position']<=res_df['end']),True,False)

df3 = res_df[(res_df['check_between']==True) |
              (res_df['start'].isnull())|
              (res_df['end'].isnull()) ]

df3.drop(['check_between','start','end'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
   Chr  position    logr    seg
0   1   50           3.0    0.2
6   1   500          4.0    0.5
12  2   1030         10.0   0.2
18  2   2005         11.0   0.1
24  3   3575         18.0   0.3
25  3   50           13.0   0.1
30  4   250          NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `left-merge` with `indicator=True`. Next, `query` checks `position` between `start`, `end` or `_merge` value is `left_only`. Finally, drop unwanted columns

```
df1.merge(df2, 'left', indicator=True).query('(start<=position<=end) | _merge.eq("left_only")') \
                                      .drop(['start', 'end', '_merge'],1)

Out[364]:
   Chr  position  logr  seg
0    1        50   3.0  0.2
6    1       500   4.0  0.5
12   2      1030  10.0  0.2
18   2      2005  11.0  0.1
24   3      3575  18.0  0.3
25   3        50  13.0  0.1
30   4       250   NaN  NaN
```